# Import wordpress blog to joomla

Tags: html, wordpress, blogs, joomla3.0, posterous

how to import my wordpress blog to my new joomla3.0 website. Any option to insert posterous backup into joomla3.0 directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a joomla plugin to do this but you have to pay:

https://compojoom.com/joomla-extensions/cmigrator

Comment: thanks for your replaying brother, is there any option througn backend(i mean with codes)?

Comment: Sure but you have to perfectly know the structure of wordpress and joomla. I personnaly don't know joomla so well, then can't really help you about the code needed to make it works. I've googled, found some code but for past versions of joomla like 1.x or 2.x

Comment: hi,what about posterous. is there any option for posterous blog backup add to in joomla3.0 directly ?

Comment: you can dig this link on joomla's official forum : http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=75574

Answer (score 3):

**WordPress to core Joomla**

There are several tools (one free) that can help with migrating WordPress to core Joomla.

CMigrator: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/19583

J2XML Wordpress Importer (**Free**): http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/extensions-specific-non-sorted/25375

JConverter: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/10237

CMS2CMS: http://www.cms2cms.com/supported-cms/wordpress-to-joomla-migration/

The J2XML free option only migrates categories and posts. The paid tools support migration of pages, users, images and comments to varying degrees.

**WordPress to Joomla Third Party Blog Extensions**

There are other options to import from WordPress into Joomla blogging extensions such as:

WordPress to JoomBlog Converter: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/21946

EasyBlog can apparently migrate a WordPress blog: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/12630

RSBlog! can apparently import a WordPress blog: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/14679

**Posterous to Joomla**

I'm not aware of any tools to import Posterous data directly into Joomla but there seem to be a few tools to import Posterous data to WordPress e.g.:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/import/import-from-posterous/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/posterous-importer/

http://lifehacker.com/5892776/how-to-back-up-and-migrate-your-posterous-spaces-to-tumblr-blogger-or-wordpress

It looks like the best course of action is to import your Posterous data into WordPress before migrating your WordPress site to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Posterous backup - sounds interesting, but I think joomla forums would be more informative in your case. They discuss your issue a lot, and it appears there are a couple ways to migrate for you.

See this thread as an example: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=796382

Best of luck, bro!